# Disable certain tags and javascript inside an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run a forum and there's an option to enable full html coding in posts. However, it does not have the option to disable javascript and  tags, to my chagrin. For security reasons, I wanted to disable them, which brings me to the question: is there any way via jquery or javascript to accomplish this? I have been searching for it but to no avail.

Note: All posts are enclosed in `<div class="postcolor"></div>` tags.

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't validating the user input blocking the posting of text which contains script tags be a more direct approach to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This question is actually more complicated then you think. Even if you remove script tags, what happens when the user inserts something like `<a href="javascript:function();">,`, or Javascript is disabled?

It would be much better to use a server-side language to do this processing for you. Since PHP is a commonly used server-side language, here's PHP's `strip_tags()` function (as an example):

```
$allowed_tags = "<p><strong><i>";
strip_tags($post, $allowed_tags);
```

Comment: I've got a noob question. Can the javascript written in the attributes affect other elements or just the element where it's written?

Comment: @Jawn: No problem, there aren't any bad questions! :) Yes, JS within attributes such as `href` can affect the entire page, call global functions, and do a lot of dangerous things. You need to make sure the user doesn't have the ability to run scripts without permission.

Comment: I see. So I really need to disable running JS within attributes too. I don't really know how to accomplish this. I'm mainly a designer, less of a coder. >.<

Comment: Yes, that's why if you can run all post code through `strip_tags()`, you'll be fine.

Answer (score -1):

No. User can disable javascript. Use (PHP) function instead

```
define('ALLOWED_TAGS', '<p><b><div><table><tr><td>'); //and more
strip_tags($message, ALLOWED_TAGS);
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not versed with PHP. I only know basic Jquery. How do you exactly write this? Thank you. :)

Comment: @Jawn: what language you use to proccess forms?

Comment: @genesis: It looks like he's using a forum framework, probably PHP.

Comment: @Jawn: What language is your forum written in? How are you receiving the post information?

Comment: @Chromium, genesis: I'm not sure, but it's hosted by JCINK.

Comment: @genesis: I'm well aware of that. I meant that it's probably a PHP-based framework.

Comment: @Chromium: The administrator functions allow me to edit the html, css and some javascript to modify some looks. But I don't think I can modify the PHP or something. :|

Comment: @Jawn: So there's no chance to allow/disallow tags.

Comment: @genesis: Aw, I see. That's a real downer but thanks a lot, sir! :)